# Reading binary file in c written in python

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy

I wrote numpy 2 dimensional float array as a binary file using

`narr.tofile(open(filename,"wb"),sep="",format='f')`

and try to retrieve the same in c using

```
FILE* fin = fopen(filename,"rb") 
float* data = malloc(rows*2*sizeof(float));
fread(data, sizeof(float), rows*2, fin);
```

This data array when printed shows different values than original array. Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: not sure if it's _the_ problem, but the 2nd argument to `fopen` is a `const char*`, so that should be `"rb"`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] writing/reading one single float. As a side effect you may fiond out yourself what's going on.

Comment: I get multiple errors and warnings when trying to compile based on your C snippet including `warning: multi-character character constant` and `error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'float*'`

Comment: @RandomDavis, use a C compiler to compiler C code.  The error about converting `void *` to `float *` is a dead giveaway that you're using a C++ compiler instead, for that conversion is perfectly valid in C without a cast.

Comment: I presume that the rows of your numpy array are two elements wide?  That's an entirely separate consideration from how many dimensions the array has.

Comment: @yano, yes you are right, just edited. The problem remains the same. Turns out I was using "rb" originally in my code

Comment: You are reading the file as if it contains a sequence of binary `float`s.  Are you certain that's the correct type?  It's at least plausible that what it actually contains is a sequence of binary `double`s.

Comment: FYI: With `sep=""`, there is no need to include the argument `format='f'`.  The `format` argument is used when a text file is written.

Comment: What is `narr.dtype`?

Comment: Overall, you've not presented enough information here.  You will greatly improve your chances of getting a good answer by presenting a [mcve].

Comment: By 2 dimensional, do you mean `Nx2`? A 2 dimentional array can be `N*M` but your C code is fixed using `2`.

Comment: @4386427 sorry for the confusion, I meant Nx2, although this can be generalized for any NxM too after this works I think

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you for that. The dtype is 'float64'

Comment: Write a simple test program. Use a single row and just 2 floats. Make the floats powers of 2 so they can be recognised easily. Then inspect the output file in a hex-editor. That should show the format used and you can check if that matches the expected input for the C-code. You could post the file if you need help.

Comment: In that case, @JohnBollinger has identified the problem.  The corresponding C type is `double`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I see. I will try with double and post later as I am away from my work desk at the moment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may depends on system you are using, `ndarray.tofile()` outputs in little-endian, which means that the  **least significant byte is stored first**, try to use `numpy.byteswap()` and then convert to file. Also try to do it without format specifier and see result. Documentation states that default value for specifier is `format="%s"`, try to put percentage symbol before your format specifier, like so `%f`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and tried both with and without % sign. Problem still remains. I am still trying to figure out if it is due to endian-ness of the data. I will try byteswap() and let you know in a while

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way if you save your data in npy format through `np.save('foo.npy',narr)`. It is a (writer and) reader for 2D npy files that returns its data as a two dimensional Eigen matrix. Note that the code does lots of assumptions and only works for 2D arrays saved with the standard np save() options.

```
// npymatrix.h
#ifndef NPYMATRIX_H
#define NPYMATRIX_H

#include <Eigen/Eigen>

// Routines for saving and loading Eigen matrices as npy files.
int npywrite(Eigen::MatrixXd& mat, const char *filename, bool do_flip_y);
int npyread(const char *filename,
            // output
            Eigen::MatrixXd& mat);

#endif /* NPYMATRIX */
```

And the C++ file:

```
// npymatrix.cc

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "npymatrix.h"

using namespace Eigen;

enum {
    FLOAT8,
    FLOAT4,
    INT8
};

static const int data_size[] = {8,4, 1};

int npywrite(MatrixXd& mat, const char *filename, bool do_flip_y)
{
    FILE *fh = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!fh)
        return -1;

    // Write header and version number to file
    fwrite("\223NUMPY"
           "\001\000"
           , 1, 8, fh);
    char header[100];
    sprintf(header,
            "{'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (%d, %d), } \n",
            mat.rows(),
            mat.cols());
    unsigned short header_len = strlen(header);
    fwrite(&header_len, 2, 1, fh);
    fwrite(header, header_len, 1, fh);

    // Is there a faster way??
    for (int row_idx=0; row_idx<mat.rows(); row_idx++) {
        for (int col_idx=0; col_idx<mat.cols(); col_idx++) {
            int r_idx = row_idx;
            if (do_flip_y)
                r_idx = mat.rows()-1-r_idx;
            double v = mat(r_idx, col_idx);
            fwrite(&v, sizeof(double), 1, fh);
        }
    }

    fclose(fh);
    return 0;
}

static const char *find_next_alphanum(const char *p)
{
    while(*p && (!isalnum(*p)))
        p++;
    return p;
}

static const char *find_next_string_after(const char *p, const char *token)
{
    p = strstr(p, token);
    if (!p)
        return p;
    return p + strlen(token);
}

static const char *find_next_alnum_after(const char *p)
{
    while(*p and isalnum(*p))
        p++;
    return p;
}

static char *strdup_to_delim(const char *p, const char *delim)
{
    const char *pstart = p;

    while(*p && !strchr(delim, *p)) 
        p++;
    return strndup(pstart, p-pstart);
}

int npyread(const char *filename,
            // output
            MatrixXd& mat)
{
    FILE *fh = fopen(filename, "rb");

    // Magic bytes
    char magic_bytes[6], version[2];
    fread(magic_bytes, 1, 6, fh);

    // Version
    fread(version, 1, 2, fh);

    // Header len
    short header_len;
    fread(&header_len, 1, 2, fh);

    // Read the header
    char *header = new char[header_len];
    fread(header, 1, header_len, fh);

    // parse the header. This is ugly but works for a standard header...
    const char *p = header;
    p = find_next_string_after(p, "descr");
    p = find_next_alphanum(p+1);
    char *descr = strdup_to_delim(p, "'\"");

    p = find_next_string_after(p, "fortran_order");
    p = find_next_alphanum(p+1);
    char *fortran_order = strdup_to_delim(p, ",");

    p = find_next_string_after(p, "shape");
    p = find_next_alphanum(p+1);
    char *shape = strdup_to_delim(p, ")");

    int height = atoi(shape);
    int width = atoi(find_next_alphanum(find_next_alnum_after(shape)));

    // Decode the type
    int dtype=-1;
    if (strcmp("<f8", descr)==0
        || strcmp("f8", descr)==0
        ) {
        dtype=FLOAT8;
    }
    else if (strcmp("<f4", descr)==0
             || strcmp("f4", descr)==0) {
        dtype=FLOAT4;
    }
    else {
        printf("Unsupported data type: %s!\n", descr);
        return -1;
    }
    int pixel_size = data_size[dtype];
    mat.setZero(height, width);
    for (int row_idx=0; row_idx<height; row_idx++) {
        for (int col_idx=0; col_idx<width; col_idx++) {
            unsigned char v[8];
            double gl;
            fread(v, 1, pixel_size, fh);
            switch(dtype) {
            case FLOAT8:
                gl = *((double*)v);
                break;
            case FLOAT4:
                gl = *((float*)v);
                break;
            default:
                gl = *((unsigned char*)v);
                break;
            }
            mat(row_idx,col_idx) = gl;
        }
    }

    fclose(fh);
    free(shape);
    free(descr);
    free(fortran_order);
    delete [] header;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am actually looking for general N x M shape matrices. This will not be adaptable for my requirements